# OutOfMemoryException when creating large ZIP file using System.IO.Packaging

Tags: c#, packaging, out-of-memory

I am trying to debug an `OutOfMemoryException` that occurs when creating a fairly large `ZIP` file using `System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage`.

The code is iterating through a large list of objects, doing the following for each object.

1. Serializing the object data to a temporary file.
2. Creating a `PackagePart` for the file.
3. Copy from a source `System.IO.Stream` to another:

   - Source stream: `FileStream`
   - Target stream: `PackagePart::GetStream()` => `MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOModeEnforcingStream`

Finally it calls `Package::Close()` which saves the file.

The problem I am having is that for a particularly large list of objects, I am seeing an `OutOfMemoryException` (the x86 process size is getting to about 1.2GB in size).

I was thinking about partitioning the object data into chunks so I only process a smaller amount per loop (i.e. steps 1-3 above).  The idea is that I would create `n` ZIP files in a temporary directory, and then find a way to combine them into a single archive.

Is this possible using `System.IO.Packaging`?  What would I use to combine the parts?

Or is there a better way to fix this?

Comment: Try calling Flush in between the iteration when creating a new package

Comment: @Ankur - you've nailed it, that seemed to do the trick.  If you upgrade your comment to an answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the `Flush` method on the Package object in between creating a new package should probably solve the problem as that would cause the memory buffer to be flushed to disk.

Comment: Thanks - this worked for me.  I ended up flushing it between every 500 files that were added to the ZIP file.  This was a good tradeoff between memory and performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the DotNetZip library (http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). I've tried several zip libraries (System.IO like you are currently using and also SharpZibLib) and by *far* the easiest to use is the DotNetZip library.

You'll almost certainly end up with fewer lines of code and I found the memory usage to be very good (had a problem in a virtual machine environment which I reported and a new release fixed it).

Comment: My original question wasn't very clear about this, but this is actually a defect in existing code and I didn't want to have to re-write this code too much (I just want to fix the crash).  I edited the question to make this more clear.